# What algorithm can be used to search text among different documents and return documents based on rank?

Tags: algorithm, search, text, nlp

Scenario  - As soon as we type something in the outlook search bar, it shows recommendations. How does it work?
In my question, I referred documents as everything that my outlook knows of. E.f. my emails, contacts etc.

E.g. if I type c it shows recommendations like calendar, cxyz@gmail.com, cabc@yahoo.com, etc. What algorithm is used that does this so quickly?

Comment: Is it all done by edit distance? If yes, then compare edit distance on each text that is present in my outlook?

Comment: have a look at Trie data structure, maybe that's what you are looking for.